# Diagonal Movement of PictureBox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to create a simple platforming game in Visual Basic as a project for school.  Although I have figured out how to move the picture up, down, left, and right using the WASD keys, I am unable to make the PictureBox move diagonally by holding two keys.  For example, the PictureBox should move diagonally to the top right when the user holds down the W and D keys.  In short, how can I move the PictureBox diagonally when the user holds two keys?

Below is the code so far.

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If DPressed = True Then
        PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left + 9
    ElseIf DPressed = True AndAlso WPressed = True Then
        PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left + 9
        PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top - 9
    ElseIf APressed = True Then
        PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left - 9
    ElseIf SPressed = True Then
        PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top + 9
    ElseIf WPressed = True Then
        PictureBox1.Top = PictureBox1.Top - 9
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        DPressed = True
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        WPressed = True
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        APressed = True
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        SPressed = True
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode And Not Keys.Modifiers) = Keys.D AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.W Then
        DPressed = True
        WPressed = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        DPressed = False
        WPressed = False
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        WPressed = False
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        APressed = False
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        SPressed = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you can not do a combo of keys like W+D.  I think they will trigger separate events key up/key down events even when used at the same time.  I'm not completely sure that e.Modifers will ever = Keys.W.  Aren't modifiers limited to the likes of CTRL. ALT?

Comment: If you care about modifiers then I suggest that you test `e.KeyData`, e.g. Ctrl+Shift+W would be detected using `If e.KeyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.Shift Or Keys.W) Then`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```vb
Private wDown As Boolean = False
Private aDown As Boolean = False
Private sDown As Boolean = False
Private dDown As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.W
            wDown = True
        Case Keys.A
            aDown = True
        Case Keys.S
            sDown = True
        Case Keys.D
            dDown = True
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.W
            wDown = False
        Case Keys.A
            aDown = False
        Case Keys.S
            sDown = False
        Case Keys.D
            dDown = False
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim xIncrement = 0
    Dim yIncrement = 0

    If wDown Then
        yIncrement -= 9
    End If

    If aDown Then
        xIncrement -= 9
    End If

    If sDown Then
        yIncrement += 9
    End If

    If dDown Then
        xIncrement += 9
    End If

    PictureBox1.Location += New Size(xIncrement, yIncrement)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try marking the DPressed, WPressed, APressed variables as ***Shared***.